# Saving function argument value for later use

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've function called `myFunction()` which will take `1` argument as input. I need to save the argument to a variable and access the input from the variable for later use.

Below is what i'm trying to achieve here.

When user make's an action a event will be passed as a argument to `Myfunction`. Inside my `myFunction` i'm assigning the event to a variable `saveArg1`.

In component x, i'm making a change will should call `myFunction` in `component 1`. I'm calling the function using `subject`.

But issue is, while calling the `myFuntion`, `saveArg1` is undefined.

So how can save a event for later use ? I dont want to use localStorage.

```
**Component 1**
public saveArg1:any;
ngOnInit(){
 this.myService.isChanged.subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
       this.myfunction(this.saveArg1);
      }
    });
}

myfunction(agr1) {
this.saveArg1 = agr1;
....
}

**Component x**
  onWeekChange($event) {
    this.myService.isChanged.next(true);
  }
```

Comment: `myFunction` does not do anything, it replaces `saveArg1` with itself

Comment: So the callback does call `myfunction` with the saved value, and `myfunction` does save its argument to be later used in the callback? That makes no sense. Where is the argument value coming from originally?

Comment: What are `agr` and `agr1`, should that be the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some initial value to your var `saveArg1`, may be empty.

In your `component 1`,

```
public saveArg1:any="";
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting this.saveArg1 also to some subject. Because your component is then created from scratch when you call `this.myService.isChanged` from other component that reason why saveArg1 is not assigned anymore.